# Multiple Record Updates are only sending one Outbound Message

Tags: visual-workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

i am currently trying to send multiple Files from Salesforce to SAP. We are using Informatica Cloud as a Middleware and the Problem is, that i need to send each File on its own. We have a custom Field named RelevantFileIds__c which contains multiple Files which are separated by a comma.

I have build a Flow which calls an Invocable Method which splits the String and returns a List of Ids. After that, i am Looping through the List and Update a Field on a Custom Object which has a Field Relevant_File_SAP__c.

My Outbound Message is sending the following Fields:

- Id
- Name
- Relevant_File_SAP__c

My Workflow Rule looks like this:

```
ISCHANGED(Relevant_File_SAP__c)
```

When i debug the Flow, the Update works as expected but the Problem is that it only fires one Outbound Message whereas i expect to have multiple Outbound Messages when there are multiple Files in the RelevantFieldsIds__c.

If you need further Information, i will provide them.

Edit:
Future Class:

```
public class TestClass {

    @future
    public static void updateRelevantFile(Id relevantFile, Id complaintId) {
        Complaint__c complaint = [SELECT Id FROM Complaint__c WHERE Id = 'a0h7a000004jflQAAQ'];
        
        System.debug('Relevant File Id: ' + relevantFile);
        
        complaint.Relevant_Files_SAP__c = relevantFile;
        
        System.debug('Complaint: ' + complaint);
        
        UPDATE complaint;
            
    }
    
}
```

Code which I have used to test the Future Class:

```
String relevantFiles = '0687a00000157f7AAA,0687a000000pfsxAAA';
List<String> split = relevantFiles.split(',');
Id complaintId = 'a0h7a000004jflQAAQ';

System.debug('Size: ' + split.size());
Integer index = 0;

for (String relevantFile : split) {
    
    index++;
    
    System.debug('Index: ' + index);
    
    TestClass.updateRelevantFile(relevantFile, complaintId);
    
}
```

[image: Field History]

Comment: For this to work, you'd have to update that field `Relevant_File_SAP__c` in 3 separate transactions (with future/queueable apex). If you're updating it in a loop in the same transaction - it doesn't matter how many times you re-assign the value in that field, it's all in one transaction. If you add field history tracking on that field, I suspect you'll see one update (which is the final file in your list).

Comment: I have never worked with Future or Queueable Apex. I have created a Class which Updates a Complaint which has the Future Annotation. In another Class i looped over the List of Ids and called the Future Method for each Entry. But i'm still getting only one Outbound Message. Can you please give me a hint how i could do it?

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to provide the code you're referring to that would help. I think adding [field history tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=5) would help to debug and confirm you see separate updates on that field for each file (or don't see that).

Comment: I have updated my original Question.

Comment: It's possibly an issue of timing where outbound messages will "update" the information if the record changes before the message is delivered - is the one outbound message sent for the last file ID? See [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_om_considerations.htm&type=0). Also make sure to check if any messages have failed in `Setup --> Monitoring --> Outbound Messages`